# Firebase Hosting - custom domain - Site Not Found

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting to host my site with a custom domain. I kept getting the error "Site Not Found," as shown below. I have CloudFlare as my domain provider, where I have configured the DNS records correctly, as Firebase is shown to be connected. I also used `whatsmydns.net` to check, and my DNS records have propagated globally. At this point, I don't know what else to do, I have tried various approaches, such as running `firebase init`, `npm run build`, `firebase deploy --only hosting`, as well as remove and add the domain on Firebase Domains. I would really appreciate your help!

[image: site-not-found]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and re-adding custom domain did the trick for me.

[image: Firebase Hosting Screenshot]